# Quest 2 cannot connect to a LAN server even I modified the Android manifest file

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, networking, lan, oculusquest

**First of all, I know Quest 2 is based on Android system, and we need to adjust the manifest file.**

I built a little network as a LAN to make my Quest 2 and the local server connect to each other.

The Quest 2 and the LAN server shared same Wi-Fi resource.

I used Unity to simulate the connection between them and it worked.

However, once I deployed the app to Quest 2, it failed to connect unexpectedly.

After doing some research, I found that it needs some adjustment of Android manifest file.

So I followed instructions:

1.Copy the Android manifest from the Temp folder to another directory.(Done)

2.Add following tow lines in the file:(Done)

```
android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET"
android.permission="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
```

3.Paste the updated manifest file into the Assets/Plugin/Android folder. (Done)

After I rebuilt it, it **successfully** built a manifest file itself according to my adjustment, but nothing changed when I tried again in Quest 2.

I am wondering that it was not the manifest but other details caused the failure, for I also built another mini app on my phone and failed, either.

Could somebody help me with this?

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of server? Android version of used device? Try a browser on your device.

Comment: @blackapps 
A customized server by myself , which is built with .NET core and runs on Windows.
Minimum of Android version is 24, and target version is 30.

Comment: Sorry, the minimum version is 7.0 (API level 24) and the target version is 11.0(API level 30)

Comment: Unanswered questions/suggestions: kind of server (smtp, http, https, ftp,..). Android version of used device. Testing with browser on device.

Comment: @blackapps The server is a UDP socket listener that can simply receive requests and send responses back. 
The Android version of used device is 11.
I also made the client app connect to google website and it worked.
So I am wondering it is not the Android but the local server caused this issue.

Comment: Unanswered: `Testing with browser on device.`. Why?